# Solving for a current using node-voltage analysis

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, current-measurement

I wish to know how I can find out what \$i_a\$ is. The answer is, according to the textbook, supposed to be **1.33 A**.

If I select the top node as a reference node, my understanding is that we then know the voltage over \$R_2\$ is 10 volts as well? I'm very confused as to how I can analyze this simple circuit.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you select the top node (I assume you mean middle/right) as your reference node, that only tells you that the top left node (at the negative terminal of the voltage source) is at -10V (because of the voltage source). It doesn't tell you the voltage across \$R_2\$.

Comment: @Null Does that mean that the current through \$R_1\$ is \$-1\, A\$?

Comment: No, the current source's current is split between the two paths (one of which is through \$R_2\$, the other is through the voltage source and \$R_1\$).

Comment: Have you heard of superposition? This would be best here.

Comment: @Null I don't think I have read about it, but I could be wrong as I'm not reading this course in english. Could you provide the method for my case?

Comment: I posted an explanation of how to use superposition here. I haven't fully solved it so you can try to work it out yourself, but feel free to comment on my answer if you need any clarification.

Comment: We made a canonical question to explain superposition: [How do I use superposition to solve a circuit?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162436/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two independent sources, so you can use [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem) to simplify this problem. Superposition says you can turn off all but one independent source and compute the contribution of the source that is on to the output (\$i_a\$ in this case); then turn on the next source with all other sources off and compute its contribution; once you have all the contributions you can sum them together for the final result.

First, turn off the current source to find the voltage source's contribution (this means the current source is set to 0A, which is equivalent to an open circuit). Now you just have one loop consisting of the voltage source and two resistors in series. I'll leave it to you to compute \$i_a\$ in that case...

Second, turn off the voltage source to find the current source's contribution (this means the voltage source is set to 0V, which is equivalent to a short circuit). Now you have a current source driving two resistors in parallel. Again, I'll leave it to you to compute \$i_a\$ in that case...

The final answer is the sum of the two contributions you found.

Comment: I have some questions so that I know when I'm allowed to utilize this theorem. In the Wiki article, it first mentions that the theorem works for bilateral linear system. What is the definition of a bilateral linear system? And also, it says that the other voltage/current sources are replaced by their internal impedence; is this just a fancy way of saying "turning off"? Also, if you're familiar with [supernodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernode_%28circuit%29), is there any way this circuit can be solved with supernodes, as this circuit was presented right after a chapter about supernodes

Comment: @B.Lee The [canonical superposition question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/162436/51760) linked to by The Photon has some good explanations on when you can use the theorem. Basically, make sure all elements are linear (e.g. no diodes) and you can only turn off the independent sources (you must leave the dependent sources on). [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7zEbl3Zu0HgC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=bilateral+linear+system&source=bl&ots=uN3WruJ5fZ&sig=FbTZfve67WmZ8_YFfioobfWGWMo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwA2oVChMIjNPo5OjbxwIVEHySCh350AuV) is a definition of "bilateral"...

Comment: @B.Lee It is true that voltage/current sources are replaced by their internal impedance when they are "turned off". However, this only matters for non-ideal sources (e.g. in the real world). Your circuit assumes ideal sources, so the voltage source has 0 internal impedance (i.e. short circuit) and the current source has infinite internal impedance (i.e. open circuit).

Comment: @B.Lee It is possible to use supernodes/[nodal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis) for this circuit and avoid all use of superposition, but the analysis is more complicated that way. If you are interested, I encourage you to practice finding the same answer using that method as well.

Comment: That was the method I first tackled, I even tried going backwards by using the answer given; to no avail however, as I just couldn't figure it out. You've helped me out enough already, so I hate bothering, but if you don't mind me asking, what would be the first step in this manner?

Comment: @B.Lee I came back to edit my answer, but someone else helpfully did it already. I think superposition is the way to go for this, but it's good to see how it's done without it.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to solve this question using Nodal analysis then this is how to go about it:

Consider the black dot on the top to be one of your Nodes. Lets call this Node A.
The other black dot becomes our Datum Node or the Node at Ground Voltage (Node B).

Next we will assume another current \$i_b\$ flowing from ground to Node A

[image]

Applying Kirchoff's Current Law at node A, we get:

$$i_b + 1 = i_a$$

Now we write this in terms of Voltages using Ohm's Law (\$V=IR\$)

Therefore,

$$\frac{0+10-V_a}{10} + 1 = \frac{V_a}{5}$$

On solving this you get \$V_a = 20/3\$ Volts.

Therefore current \$i_a = V_a/5 = 20/(5 \times 3) = 4/3 = 1.33\$ A