# Using superposition to solve circuit with one voltage source and a dependent source

Tags: theory

If i use super position to solve a circuit with one voltage source and one current dependent voltage source, does it make sense to use superposition to eliminate the independent voltage source, and do mesh analysis, and then turn on the independent voltage source and do mesh analysis again, and add the results of the two?

Or should i also turn off the dependent voltage source when i turn on the independent source to do the analysis?

Comment: Related: [How do I use superposition to solve a circuit?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162436/how-do-i-use-superposition-to-solve-a-circuit)

Answer (score 2):

Superposition is a technique for solving linear circuits with multiple independent sources. It does not help to solve a circuit with only one independent source.

Imagine you solved your circuit with the independent source zero'd out. All of the resulting node voltages and branch circuits would be zero. Therefore the dependent source value would be zero. You'd obtain no useful information.

> Or should i also turn off the dependent voltage source when i turn on the independent source to do the analysis?

Dependent sources and independent sources are completely different animals.

Dependent sources only produce voltages or currents in response to signals generated by the independent sources and they are never zero'd when solving by superposition.

Consider that you can think of a resistor as a CCVS whose sense and output branches happen to be connected in series with each other. And you certainly don't remove any resistors from your circuit when solving the circuit.