# Voltage divider output / OP amp

Tags: voltage-divider

I have a voltage divider, and the output goes to OP amp.

This is from my schoolwork.

-1 to +1 input
|
[R1] 1000 ohms
|
---> output to op amp
|
[R2] 1000 ohms
|
2v

How do I calculate output that goes to op amp?
Regular voltage divider formula is
Vout=Vin×(R2÷(R1+R2))
But lets say V1 is -1 and other end is 2v, what do i take for Vin? 3 volts?

Edit:
Found the whole exercise
[image]

V1 is 4v
V2 is from -1v to 1v
And where the ground symbol is, there should be 2v. What do I take for V2 in formula whem V2 is -1 or +1?

Comment: Could you add a schematic? Your ASCII art is a bit difficult to understand. There's a button up on top of the editor pane that allows you to add a schematic.

Comment: It would be more clear what you're asking if you included a schematic. But I think what you are looking for is \$V_o=V_- + (V_+-V_-)\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ which is the formula for the output from a voltage divider connected between voltages \$V_-\$ and \$V_+\$.

Comment: There is no R2 in your schematic, so it's not clear what's the connection from the schematic to your formulas.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more clear what you're asking if you included a schematic.

But I think what you are looking for is \$V_o=V_- + (V_+-V_-)\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$ which is the formula for the output from a voltage divider connected between voltages \$V_-\$ and \$V_+\$.

You can derive this formula yourself using the [principle of superposition](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162436/).