# How do I find the open circuit voltage of this circuit?

Tags: thevenin

I'm trying to find the Thevenin equivalent of the following circuit, but am unsure of how to find the Thevenin voltage/open circuit voltage. Can I just find the voltage across the current source and the voltage across the 4k resistor and add them together to get the open circuit voltage?

[image]

Comment: See [How do I use superposition to solve a circuit?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162436/)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just find the voltage across the current source and the voltage
>   across the 4k resistor and add them together to get the open circuit
>   voltage?

Yes, that's going to give you the right answer but finding those voltages requires a little thought. For instance you have to notice that the current through the 1kohm resistor is 9 mA and some of that comes via the 2k and some via the 3k so you have to proportion them appropriately AND keep the relevancy of the 45 volt source and 4kohm in mind.

It might be easier to solve it using superposition.

Comment: How about node voltage method?

Comment: Superposition will be the easiest. Replace the 45v source with a short circuit and compute the currents due to the 9mA source. Open circuit the current source, and compute the currents due to the voltage source. Add all the component currents. Find the voltages from V=IR.