# Is voltage divider applicable on circuits where there is no ground?

Tags: voltage-divider

For the circuit below, if the bottom terminal is -Vin and not grounded, is applying voltage divider possible at all?

If this is the case, what would the equation be? I never heard of a voltage divider with no reference ground at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: See [How do I use superposition to solve a circuit?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162436/). Once you've worked through it once by superposition you'll see it's easy to reduce the solution to a simple formula.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Consider a more general case and apply the [superposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_theorem):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSNGIL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$ V_o = V_o(V1) + V_o(V2) = V1 \frac{R2}{R1+R2} + V2 \frac{R1}{R1+R2}$$

Answer (score 11):

"Ground" is (usually) just a label we put on the point in a circuit that we want to call "Zero Volts" -it has no special magic properties.

A voltage divider will work whether or not one end of it is connected to "Ground".  Vout is still proportional to the resistor values, but the total voltage is Vin-Vb (Vb = voltage at the bottom of R2), and will be shifted by the difference in voltage between Vb "ground".

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The analysis is really straightforward. Let's say you have Vin1 (the positive input) and Vin2 (the negative input). The derivation is as follows (with \$i\$ being the current flowing through R1,R2):

$$
i = \frac{V_{in1}-V_{in2}}{R_1 + R_2} \\
V_{OUT} = V_{in_2} + i R_2 = V_{in_1} - i R_1
$$

It's still a voltage divider, but the "lower end" isn't 0V anymore. Still has its uses, but not as common.