# Superposition theorem with phasors

Tags: phasor, superposition

Can someone explain the superposition theorem step by step when applied with phasors (AC circuits)? 
I think books and websites mostly include examples of how to solve something with superposition but not enough detailed theory.

Comment: This question ("explain...step by step") is very broad. There are many tutorial resources for this on line. Why don't you show us what you do know about superposition and phasors, then try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: See [How do I use superposition to solve a circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/162436/6334). The method doesn't depend on whether the sources are DC or AC steady state. You just have to use phasors (complex numbers) for the AC case instead of real numbers.

Comment: I do not know what steps you need.  A phasor just expresses a voltage or current in a way that captures both the magnitude of a sine wave and it's phase relative to a reference.  It's just a shorthand.  If you can add \$A_1 \cos \omega + \phi_1 + A_2 \cos \omega + \phi_2\$, then you can do that sum with phasors.

Comment: Try giving us an example and show us how you work through it.  End your question with "what am I doing wrong?".  Then your question will be nice and specific, and we can help you out.