# Finding current in RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, passive-networks, homework

I am given the following circuit:

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which R0 do you want the current through? The horizontal one or the vertical one?

Comment: Highly related: [How do I use superposition to solve a circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/162436/6334).

Comment: @ThePhoton horizontal

Comment: Use a simulator is a good start. Of course, if this is a homework question you need to show where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the current through the horizontal R0, you can,

1. Combine all the other passive devices using series and parallel combinations. Since you have two source frequencies, you'd do this calculation separately for each frequency.
2. Use superposition

   A. Find the current through R0 due to each of the sources.

   B. Sum these currents to get the total current through R0.